# Recursive Update of 1-in-K Choice Probabilities

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

I need to model and track K class of likely events that can happen, each with certain associated probabilities. I am planning to model probabilities with multinoulli distribution. My question is how to update these probabilities recursively when at each time step $t$ I am given, not specific events, but "soft events" again probabilities associated to a likely event. Let's say I am modeling a die, I start out with 1/6 for each choice, but at each time step I am not told it was a 3, or 4, or 1, but $[1/4,1/4,1/8,1/8,1/8,1/8]$, in this case, the die was most likely 1 or 2. I don't want to lose these probabilities, I'd like to make the update as "soft as possible".

Can I use Dirichlet conjugate prior in this case, or should I look elsewhere (like maximum likelihood, MAP, etc) for this? Or use Dirichlet as the base, and update that.

[Here](http://andrewgelman.com/2009/04/29/conjugate_prior/) Andrew Gelman says instead of using Dirichlet, use an appropiately parametrized Normal distribution. How would I do the update in this case?

Note: I would like more recent data to have more weight, as in Kalman Filters.

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a while I toyed with the idea of using mixture of Gaussians, then seeing the problem akin to log-odds representation of occupancy, i.e. in robotics, for occupancy mapping, and using the appropriate filtering method to update - but a simpler way would be just using exponentially weighted moving average, on the probabilities themselves. There is a recursive equation for it,

$$ y_t = \alpha x_t + (1-\alpha)y_{t-1} $$

where $y_t$ is the average, and $\alpha$ defines how much weight to assign to new data as opposed to old data.

An example

```
x = [[0.3,0.3,0.4], [0.1,0.1,0.8], [0.3,0.5,0.2], [0.3,0.3,0.4], [0.7,0.2,0.1]]
x = np.array(x)
y = np.array([0.33, 0.33, 0.33])
alpha = 0.8
for i in range(1,len(x)):
    y = alpha*x[i] + (1-alpha)*y
print y, np.sum(y)
```

The result

```
[ 0.618768  0.225168  0.156048] 0.999984
```

I was worried the sum would degrade and not be 1, but this is not the case.